# Local maxima 3D array python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to find the local maxima in a 3D numpy array, but I can't seem to find an easy way to do that using numpy, scipy, or anything else.

For now I implemented it using `scipy.signal.argrelexrema`. But it's very long to process large arrays, and only works on separated axes.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema


def local_maxima_3D(data, order=1):
    """Detects local maxima in a 3D array

    Parameters
    ---------
    data : 3d ndarray
    order : int
        How many points on each side to use for the comparison

    Returns
    -------
    coordinates : ndarray
        coordinates of the local maxima
    values : ndarray
        values of the local maxima
    """
    # Coordinates of local maxima along each axis
    peaks0 = np.array(argrelextrema(data, np.greater, axis=0, order=order))
    peaks1 = np.array(argrelextrema(data, np.greater, axis=1, order=order))
    peaks2 = np.array(argrelextrema(data, np.greater, axis=2, order=order))

    # Stack all coordinates
    stacked = np.vstack((peaks0.transpose(), peaks1.transpose(),
                         peaks2.transpose()))

    # We keep coordinates that appear three times (once for each axis)
    elements, counts = np.unique(stacked, axis=0, return_counts=True)
    coords = elements[np.where(counts == 3)[0]]

    # Compute values at filtered coordinates
    values = data[coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], coords[:, 2]]

    return coords, values
```

I know this solution is far from optimal and only works with order=1. Is there any better way to find local maxima in a 3D array in Python?

Comment: Do you know anything about the data? If they're determined by a formula, then you should consider getting an analytical answer. Otherwise, the data being continuous, derivable and/or single-maximum would allow for your use of an optimizer, especially if you can provide a gradient function.

Comment: As opposed to `unique(stacked(...))[where(counts==3)]`, have you tried set intersection, like `set(peaks0) & set(peaks1) & set(peaks2)`.  Of course, the `peaks#` coordinates would need to be converted into something hashable (tuples) in order to create the sets.  I don’t know if this would be faster, so this is an experiment not an answer ...